# Bluetooth capable Photo Camera that can connect to iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, camera

Does anybody know of a photo camera that is bluetooth capable, and can be programmatically accessed through the iPhone/iPad using (probably) the External Accessory framework? I know it has to be developed under Apple's MFi licensee program, but I can't seem to find any cameras that are.

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 0):

should be possible ..
see this http://www.bluetooth.com/English/SIG/MikesBlog/Posts.aspx?ID=2057

This is done via applications running on both the iPad & iPhone.

There are also several apps for IP cameras where you can view / capture pictures from the camera on the iPhone/iPad

Comment: I have some use cases where the iPhone's camera is not useful, reason why I was looking into the External Accessory framework and third party cameras that can provide a much higher picture quality. In the end, I might just go with Camera's that support Wi-Fi (through an add-on device), or use flash cards like Eye-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to find any answers, and after considering the disadvantages of using Bluetooth (transfer rate mainly), I decided to go with using Wi-Fi instead. Plenty of options there.

Comment: Samsung CL80 has bluetooth , but it has wifi too.. WiFi seems to be the better option.. I was surprised that Bluetooth enabled cameras are rare.